# Layout for a flowchart

Tags: gui-design, flowcharts

I have a flowchart with 5 nodes.  the connections are as follows:
A-B
A-C
A-D
B-C
B-D
D-C
B-E
A & E are my start and end points.
What is the best way to lay out the flowchart to maximize clarity? (I keep finding too many overlapping lines.)

Comment: As I suspected there is no perfect answer but the two solutions posted are nice.

Answer (score 4):

Does using color help?  Try using matching colors on the nodes of the flow chart and the connectors like so...

[image: color flow chart nodes and paths]

Answer (score 3):

They will overlap unless you lift some nodes above the plane where the rest are.

Another way to avoid overlapping would be show only connections that matter in given period of time/for given point.

[image]

Comment: this is nice idea for highlighting only part of a complex flow at a time.  what tool did you use to create this diagram Zoe?

Comment: @DaveAlger Thanks! I used Illustrator. I need to design or prototype datavis quite often, so it comes handy.